# The simple django model for selectbox

Tags: python, django

Django model with models.Choices

```
class Special(models.Choices):
    SPECIAL = (("welcome","My Welcome!"),
    ("privacy","my Privacy list"),
     ("happy","How happy you are"),
     ('',"-------------"))
```

and I have this code in form class

```
key_selector = forms.fields.ChoiceField(
    choices = Special.SPECIAL
    required=False,
    widget=forms.widgets.Select
)
```

This error comes here

```
TypeError: 'Special' object is not iterable
```

How can I make the selectbox with django???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
key_selector = forms.fields.ChoiceField(
    choices = Special.SPECIAL.choices
    required=False,
    widget=forms.widgets.Select
)
```

should work

Comment: Thank you I should use `choices`, it might be a basic....